# Load multiple images using for loop Firebase Storage with Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to load a list of picture store in Firebase Storage through url stored in Firestore Database. An array of itemcode (ie. **mrCodeArray**) is input, and is intended to:

- Load the url of image for each itemcode from Firestore Database (some itemcode may had multiple url store as array in the database)
- Load all images for each itemcode from Firestore Database (preferably in reverse order as the array)
- Show the itemcode and images of that code as a list

While trying to call the function **mrPicCall**, it failed to load the picture for itemcode with multiple images, while running smoothly with all the itemcode with only 1 image. I understand that Firebase proceed download requests simultaneously and had add some completion handlers to help, but it seems not useful. Do anyone had any ideas on how to achieve this?

Here is the code for the function:

```
func mrPicCall(MRCode: [MRCode]) {
    self.mrCodeArray = MRCode.map { $0.code }
    self.imageurls = []
    self.selectedImages = [:]
    self.i = 0
    self.j = 0
    
    mrPicLoad() { (complete) in
        print(complete)
        self.booMRPicLoad = true
    }
}

func mrPicLoad(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    self.j = self.mrCodeArray.count
    
    for index in 0...(j - 1) {
        mrPicLoop(index: index) { (complete) in
            print(complete)
            
            if self.mrPicResponse.count == (self.j) {
                completion("5. MR list loaded!")
            }
        }
    }
}

func mrPicLoop(index: Int, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    let itemcode = mrCodeArray[index]
    
    loadPicDataFromStroage(itemcode: itemcode) { (complete) in
        print(complete)
        self.mrPicResponse.updateValue(MRPicResponse(selectedImages: self.selectedImages), forKey: index)
        completion("4. \(itemcode): Item \(index + 1) loaded.")
    }
}

func loadPicDataFromStroage(itemcode: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    // Get data from img database
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let docRef = db.collection("img_database").document(itemcode)
    
    self.imageurls = []
    self.selectedImages = [:]
    
    docRef.getDocument { snapshot, error in
        if error == nil && snapshot != nil {
            self.imageurls = snapshot!["url"] as! [String]
            self.imageurls.reverse()
            
            self.loadMRImageFromURL(itemcode: itemcode) { (complete) in
                print(complete)
                completion("3. \(itemcode): All image data loaded!")
            }
        } else {
            self.errMRPic = true
            print(error as Any)
        }
    }
}

func loadMRImageFromURL(itemcode: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    self.i = imageurls.count
    
    for index in 0...(i - 1) {
        loopThroughImageLoad(index: index, itemcode: itemcode) { (complete) in
            print(complete)
            
            if self.selectedImages.count == (self.i) {
                completion("2. \(itemcode): All images loaded!")
            }
        }
    }
}

func loopThroughImageLoad(index: Int, itemcode: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    let value = imageurls[index]
    
    loadImageFromStorage(picurl: value) { (imageLoaded) in
        self.selectedImages.updateValue(imageLoaded, forKey: index)
        completion("1. \(itemcode): Image \(index + 1) loaded.")
    }
}

func loadImageFromStorage(picurl: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
    let storageRef = storage.reference()
    let fileRef = storageRef.child(picurl)
    fileRef.getData(maxSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
        if error == nil && data != nil {
            if let image = UIImage(data: data!) {
                completion(image)
            }
        } else {
            self.errMRPic = true
            print(error as Any)
        }
    }
}
```

I am thinking the issue may related to my use of **i** and **j** as counter, but still have no idea on how to fix this.

Comment: With multiple photos selected are you seeing all your debug messages? Such as up to this point `completion("5. MR list loaded!")` ? If not, what is the last message you see on your end?

Comment: @NashEquilibrium No. For example if mrCodeArray = [ACET04, SIMV01], where ACET04 had 3 images and SIMV01 had 1:
`1. ACET04: Image 3 loaded.
1. SIMV01: Image 1 loaded.
1. ACET04: Image 1 loaded.
1. ACET04: Image 2 loaded.
2. ACET04: All images loaded!
3. ACET04: All image data loaded!
4. ACET04: Item 1 loaded.`
And then it stucks